# Sum of infinitely many integrals

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, integration, convergence-divergence

I know that $\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{x^2+1} \, dx=\dfrac{\pi}{2}$. What if I integrate $f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x^2+1}$ in infinite disjoint integrals not of the same length, like
$$\int_{x_{1}}^{x_{2}} f(x)\,dx+\int_{x_3}^{x_4} f(x)\,dx+\cdots +\int_{x_{2k+1}}^{x_{2k+2}} f(x)\,dx+\cdots$$ Is the sum of these integrals finite?

Comment: Do these intervals overlap at all?  That is, can you have a set of intervals like: $\{[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], \ldots\}$

Comment: no. it's more like $x_{1}<x_{2}<x_{3}<\cdots <x_{2k+1}<\cdots$ so that $[x_{1},x_{2}]\cap [x_{3},x_{4}]= \emptyset$ and so on. Think of it like $\{ [1,2], [3,4], [5,6],\cdots \}$ but not necessarily of the same length.

Comment: Ah.  Should have noticed the "disjoint" part of your question.  `:)`  (oops)

Comment: You shouldn't say "infinite intervals" if you mean "infinitely many intervals".  The term "infinite intervals" means "intervals, each of which is infinite".

Comment: you are right..my bad! don't know if i can change the title though

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This amounts to show that $\int_{\Bbb{R}} g_{n} $ converges as $n \to \infty$, where

$$ g_{n}(x) = f(x) \sum_{k=1}^{n} \mathbf{1}_{[x_{2k-1}, x_{2k}]}(x). $$

The condition shows that $0 \leq g_n \leq f$, thus the dominated convergence theorem guarantees the convergence.

Comment: i don't quite understand the summation.. what if i had that $f(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2+1}$?

Comment: @HuawL, In your original question, you specified that $f(x) = \frac{1}{x^2 + 1}$, which is a non-negative integrable function. That's why I did not care the signature problem. If you are going to change $f$ to another integrable function, then $0 \leq |g_n| \leq |f|$ still makes things work.

Comment: in the summation you mean that $g_{n}(x)$ equals $f(x)$ only over the $[x_{2k-1},x_{2k} ]$ intervals?

Comment: @HuawL, absolutely right. For each subset $A \subset \Bbb{R}$, we define the function $\mathbf{1}_{A} : \Bbb{R} \to \{ 0, 1 \}$ as $$\mathbf{1}_{A}(x) = \begin{cases}1 & x \in A \\ 0 & x \notin A \end{cases}. $$ This is called the *indicator function* of $A$ for some obvious reason.

Comment: cool! thanx for your help m8!